# Can (should) you have a form with two submit options?

Tags: user-expectation, ux-integration

I've got an app that lets you start an event and give it a name.  This main event can have subevents.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to present that to the user.  They start or join an event, and then have the option to start a subevent relating to that parent event, but they could also just start a totally new event.

Has anyone seen examples of this or have ideas?  Should everything be totally separate?  As a developer I hate duplicating code like having multiple forms with the same functionality, but I'd rather the user have a good experience. To me I understand what I'm trying to accomplish by a form with two submit options...but I'm building it.  Will the user?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just because you're presenting it as two different forms doesn't mean that they need to be implemented by two different code. The form handler can be the same, with just different presentation of the form.

Comment: Well I am presenting the form different, but the problem right now is the fields are still the same so grabbing the values on the backend is being "confused" in the code.  This is because both forms are present at the same time on the page.

Comment: you can have multiple form elements in a single page, only one will be submitted at a time. Or you can

Comment: I would do it diffrent. I would split the things into "Create Subevent" and "Create Event" because the User propably knows in the beginning what he wants to enter. The "Create Event" is triggered when the user hasnt selected any event. The subevent-Button shows when the User is in the Overview (or similar) of the event. Trim down to a single sibmit option but make the us er choose between before he gets the create-screen

Answer (score 2):

Two submit buttons sounds fairly confusing to me.

I would have the user create an event and then simply offer then the chance to save that event - once saved the user can edit the event: delete it or add a sub-event.

The simple rule of thumb here is probably "don't subject your users to problems with your coding solution": Your users aren't interested in how the systems/application has been coded - they're only interested in whether they can achieve what they want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts on this:

1. Only offer the subevent action on the event details page. If you want to make it easier for users to create a subevent immediately after creating an event, offer the action "Go to event details" after creating the event. So, after creating an event, the two actions would be:

   - Go to event details
   - Create new event
2. Take a look at "Sign up/log in" forms that are common on many websites. For example, on Fandango, you have three different options when purchasing a ticket: sign into your account, create a new account, or purchase as a guest. All three options are clear and described with very simply copy. [image: Fandango checkout]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a layout that you can use for creating an **event** and a **subevent**, in the layout you have the main form for creating the event, and in the down for you have the option to create *subevents*, every subevent that you add will be shown in a list to inform the user the subevents has created.

[image: Layout]